Key 1 not working, and many 1s appear when the machine is booting. No light too on the keyboard. Reinstalled but not helpful
My keyboard's 1 key stopped working suddenly and then I had trouble with the restart. Many 1s would appear during the boot like it was being pressed. I tried disabling the keyboard too using xinput but the same happens while restarting.
Sometimes the trackpad also stops working and few other keys like left control button.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Bad keyboard needs replacing. Not an OS issue.
